# implementing explicit list memory allocation on array in c

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I have an array which is initialized in `main` function, and I want to use this array as my memory block. and implement my own malloc function on it.
but before calling my malloc on this array, I need to initiate it as a memory block of my own so I can then use it.

Now I have a function called `init(void *ptr, int size)` the `ptr` void pointer is the beginning of the array and `size` is the size of the array.

This function is supposed to initiate the array as a memory block. 
I am using [explicit list allocation](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse351/10sp/lectures/15-memallocation.pdf) (page 15), so in the init I will basically have a global pointer point at the beginning of the array, then I will set up a header on the memory:

```
- flag: block is free or allocated 'in init function it will be free'.
- size: the size of the array.
- *next: which points at the next free block.
- *prev: points at the previous free block.
```

Now my problem is how to fill the header, my current " nonfunctional code is:

```
  void init_mem(void *ptr, unsigned int size)
{

 GLOBAL_POINTER = ptr;

 *(char *)ptr = FREEMEM; // FREEMEM is a const which : free memory block

  // ptr + 1 is the second spot on the memory block, for the size of the array
 *((char *)ptr + 1) = size - sizeof(int) - (sizeof(char *) * 3);

  //because the ehole memory block is free now, the next and prev pointers points to the same block
 *((char **)ptr + 3) = (char *)ptr;
 *((char **)ptr + 4) = (char *)ptr;


}
```

My problem is now setting this info, and the concerns are :

- should i cast the `ptr` to a primitive type so I can use it, and if yes, what type is appropriate, because `int` takes 4 bytes, where `char` takes 1 and so on, so what is the right way to do it and is there a way to do it with outcasting.
- if I don't cast, then how to do the pointers arithmetic `*((char *)ptr + 1)` to move in the memory spots, because if you do pointers arithmetic on the void pointer, it through the error  `expression must be a pointer to a complete object type`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to avoid causing yourself grief, I would recommend doing all pointer arithmetic using `void` pointers and then casting the result to an appropriate pointer type after. For instance, in the line

```
*((char **)ptr + 3) = (char *)ptr;
```

you are actually adding `3*sizeof(char**)` instead of 3 bytes. Using `void*` for arithmetic fixes this problem. The size of an `int` in C can be 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform, so you will need to use `sizeof`. I think this is what you want:

```
void init_mem(void* ptr, unsigned int size)
{

    GLOBAL_POINTER = ptr;

    *(void**)ptr = FREEMEM; // FREEMEM is a const which : free memory block

    // the second spot on the memory block, for the size of the array
    *(unsigned int*)(ptr + sizeof(void*)) = size - sizeof(unsigned int) - 3 * sizeof(void*);

    //because the ehole memory block is free now, the next and prev pointers points to the same block
    *(void**)(ptr + sizeof(void*) + sizeof(unsigned int)) = ptr;
    *(void**)(ptr + 2 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(unsigned int)) = ptr;

}
```

Assuming that `FREEMEM` is a pointer type, as your size calculation seems to indicate.

Comment: Thank you, but This is generates an error "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" when trying to do pointer arithmetic on void pointers!.. that was part of the question, that how to do the asthmatics without casting, can you please provide more info, or maybe i got something wrong!

Comment: The problem there was that you where trying to dereference a void pointer directly. Arithmetic with void pointers is no problem, but you cannot dereference a void pointer without a cast.